# How to write javascript code for BMI_Calculator.html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm supposed to write javascript code for an html page that will calculate a persons BMI and tell them what it means (the number). The rules of the test were to not change the html on the page, but to just write the javascript code and link it to the html page. That's all. I have copied the html page just in case you guys might wanna have a look at it. Here is what the BMI Calculator is supposed to do using javascript:

- Person enters name, selects gender, enters weight and height. The application will calculate the persons BMR, BMI, and tell what it means (i.e. saying "you are too thin", "you are healthy", or "you are overweight").
  and it will display an image of a thin, healthy, or overweight person which is a png image.
- If they do not enter a name, an error message prompts them to enter a name. The name must be at least five characters long.
- If they do not select a gender, then an error message prompts them to please select a gender. The gender is represented by a radio button. The user selects male or female.
- If the user does not enter a weight, an error message prompts them to please enter a weight.
- If height is not entered, an error message prompts them to please enter a height.
- If you are a male, you're BMR is calculated as: BMR = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age+5).
- If you are a female, you're BMR is calculated as: BMR = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age-161).
- If the BMI is less than 18.5: "you are too thin".
- If the BMI is between 20 to 25: "you are healthy".
- If the BMI is greater than 25: "you are overweight".

Also, please don't put the question on hold or delete it. This is important for me and I need help. If you want help, please don't. It took me a long time to write this question.

Here is the html that I am supposed to write the javascript code for:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> BMI Calculator </title>
  <style>
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 25px;
    }
    button {
      height:30px;
      margin: 5px 0px;
    }
    fieldset {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #errMsg {
      color: red;
    }
    #frm {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
    }
    #imgSec {
      float: left;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      border-left: 3px solid darkblue;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- link to javascript file -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="BMI_javascript.js">
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="title"><h3>BMI Calculator</h3></div>
  <section id="frm">
    <form name="bmiForm" onsubmit="return false;">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter your Details:</legend>
        <label for="user">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" size="25" required> <br />
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="rbMale" name="gender"> Male 
        <input type="radio" id="rbFemale" name="gender">Female  <br />
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" size="10" required> <br />
        <label for="weight">Weight(kg):</label> 
        <input type="number" id="weight" size="10" required> <br />
        <label for="height">Height(cm):</label>
        <input type="number" id="height" size="10" required> <br />
        <div id="errMsg"></div>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate BMI</button>
      <button type="reset" onclick="clearErr()">Reset</button>
      <br>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Result:</legend>
        <label for="bmr">Your BMR: </label>
        <input type="text" name="bmr" id="bmr" size="18" readonly><br />
        <label for="bmi">Your BMI: </label>
        <input type="text" name="bmi" id="bmi" size="10" readonly><br />
        <label for="meaning">This Means: </label>
        <input type="text" name="meaning" id="meaning" size="25" readonly><br/>
      </fieldset>
    </section>
    <section id="imgSec">
      <img id="img" src="" height="250px">     
    </section>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript I wrote for it. I know it's horrible. The problem is the code does not work. Nothing works.

```
 function GenderType() {
   var GenderType = document.getElementsByName("rbMale","rbFemale");

   if(rbMale == "Male") {
     GenderType.innerHTML = "Male";
   } else {
     rbFemale == "Female";
     GenderType.innerHTML = "Female";
   }     
 }

 function validate() {
   var name = document.getElementById("name");
   var age = document.getElementById("age");
   var male = document.getElementById("male");
   var female = document.getElementById("female");
   var weight = document.getElementById("weight");
   var height = document.getElementById("height");          

   error = false;

   var reName = /^[a-zA-Z ]{5,}$/;
   if (reName.test(name.value) == false) {
     nameError.innerHTML = "Name must be eight letters or more";
     error = true;
   } else {
     nameError.innerHTML = "";
   }

   age = parseInt(age.value);
   if ( isNaN(age)  || age < 0 || age > 65) {
     ageError.innerHTML = "Age must be in range 0-65";
     error = true;
   } else {
     ageError.innerHTML = "";
   }

   weight = parseInt(weight.value);
   if ( isNaN(weight) || weight < 0) {
     weightError.innerHTML = "Weight must be greater than 0";
     error = true;
   } else {
     weightError.innerHTML = "";
   }

   height = parseInt(height.value);
   if (isNaN(height) || height < 0) {
     heightError.innerHTML = "height must be greater than 0"
     error = true;
   } else {
     heightError.innerHTML = "";
   }

   if ( !male.checked & !female.checked) {
     genderError.innerHTML = "Select value";
     error = true;
   } else {
     genderError.innerHTML = "";    
   }                    
 }

 function BMRCalculate () {
   if ( validate()==false ) {
     var GenderType = document.getElementById("rbMale","rbFemale").value;
     var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
     var female = document.getElementById("rbFemale");
     var male = document.getElementById("rbMale");
     var weight = document.getElementById("weight");
     var height = document.getElementById("height");
     var BMIValue = weight/( (height/100)*(height/100) );
     var BMRValue;
     var ThisMeans = document.getElementById("meaning");

     if(GenderType == male) {
       BMRValue = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age+5);
     } else {
       GenderType = female;
       BMRValue = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age-161);
   }

   if (BMIValue<18.5) {
     ThisMeans = "you are too thin";
     document.write(ThisMeans);
   } else if (BMIValue>18.5 && BMIValue<25) {
     ThisMeans = "you are healthy";
     document.write(ThisMeans);
   } else {
     ThisMeans = "You are not healthy";
     document.write(ThisMeans);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your js function is called: `function BMRCalculate ()` but in your html you have: `<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate BMI</button>`. why?

Comment: @user272976 ok I think I know what you mean. first thing I should do is change the name from BMRCalculate () to Calculate BMI () I will do it thank you god bless you. Is there anything else that I should change like should I pass the function some parameters?

Comment: @gavgrif I don't know in the exam they told me BMR is calculated differently and BMI is calculated differently so I tried to do something anything in test and this is what I could do. They said BMI is equal to  weight/( (height/100)*(height/100) ); and BMR if male = BMRValue = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age+5); also BMR if female = 10*(weight+6.25)*(height-5)*(age-161);

Comment: When naming the variables you should try to keep with the conventions and even more important to be consistent. In JavaScript you name a function with capital letter if it is a constructor. Use rather camelCase, something like this: `myFunctionName`, `myVariableName`, and keep that throughout the whole script.

Comment: Also use the builtin functions. Instead of `(height/100) * (height/100)` write `Math.pow(height/100, 2)`. In your last if condition you can move the `document.write(ThisMeans)` outside the condition block. When comparing the values pay attention on the break points. Having BMI of 18.5 would produce "You are not healthy", but that's not what you expect.

Comment: @cezar I know what you mean what I wrote is kinda messy and confusing I will try to write it again using camelCase.

Comment: Thank you all I really appreciate you taking the time to answer thank you god bless you all

Comment: This is a prime example of a poor question. Sorry, but it should be closed. Learn to write [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) questions. Copying and pasting the entire project and asking why it doesn't work is not useful to readers, regardless of its complexity.

Comment: @cezar thank you Cezar I will try to use the builtin functions of JavaScript up until now I did not know that there were builtin functions in JavaScript thank you and bless you you're feedback is extremely appreciated thank you

Comment: @Brett no please don't close the question so many people are helping, you want don't look at the JavaScript I wrote my coding is bad ok, just look at the html file of the bmi calculator from the teacher and tell me what I should do? Or how would you do it? Because that was what I was supposed to do in the test look at the html page and start from scratch a JavaScript file that will make it all work

Comment: @hugh0210 I empathize with you, but this is not a website for hiring tutors or having strangers do your homework for you. Why can't you ask your teacher for help? Isn't that their job?

Comment: @Brett I understand it's okay if you put it on hold or something I'm sorry. The problem is my teacher often says that she is too busy and that I have to pick up from someone else and my classmates they don't help at all their response to me is usually "what do I look like to you a teacher?" And I usually am lost at that point

Answer (score 0):

Mate, @gavgrif gave you some very good tips, but about the code...try to start over and think the problem again.